# Browser cookie expire handling

Tags: javascript, session-cookies

Is there a function that can be triggered in javascript once a session cookie expires? Or do I have to have a set timeout function in javascript that checks the existence of a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know when a cookie expires , so i guess there is no function which does what you are asking . 
 The best way is to check the existence , as you said.